# MySQL: How to use COALESCE with a SET datatype?

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I'm generating a view from a table, where one column is the COALESCE of 2 other columns of SET datatype. Both initial columns have the same SET type, but the type for the COALESCE is generated as a varchar. I would like it to be a SET datatype, like the original ones.

```
CREATE TABLE Items(
  id int,
  name tinytext,
  size int,
  back SET('red','green','blue','yellow'),
  front SET('red','green','blue','yellow')  
);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SimpleItems AS
SELECT id, name, COALESCE(front, back) as color
FROM Items;

INSERT INTO Items VALUES (1, 'A', 10, 3, 4);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (2, 'B', 12, 8, 9);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (3, 'C', 10, 5, 7);
```

This is a simplified setup, but it shows the issue.

In the view I want the *color* to be equal to *front*, unless *front* is NULL, then I want it to be equal to *back*. But even though both *back* and *front* are of datatype SET, the *color* is of datatype varchar.

Am I doing it wrong, or is this not possible?

UPDATE:
I am using the SET as a bitmap and filtering by enabled bits, and that's not possible when it is converted into a text (varchar). If it was represented as a number, it would be fine.

Comment: What difference does it make? When values of a `SET` type are returned, they're returned as strings.

Comment: I'm using the set as a bitmap to filter by enabled bits

Answer (score 0):

All is set like the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html) said

> If a number is stored into a SET column, the bits that are set in the binary representation of the number determine the set members in the column value. For a column specified as SET('a','b','c','d'), the members have the following decimal and binary values.

```
SET Member  Decimal Value   Binary Value
'a'          1               0001
'b'          2               0010
'c'          4               0100
'd'          8               1000
```

> If you assign a value of 9 to this column, that is 1001 in binary, so the first and fourth SET value members 'a' and 'd' are selected and the resulting value is 'a,d'.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Items(
>   id int,
>   name tinytext,
>   size int,
>   back SET('red','green','blue','yellow'),
>   front SET('red','green','blue','yellow')  
> );
>
> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SimpleItems AS
> SELECT id, name, COALESCE(front, back) as color
> FROM Items;
>
> INSERT INTO Items VALUES (1, 'A', 10, 3, 4);
> INSERT INTO Items VALUES (2, 'B', 12, 8, 9);
> INSERT INTO Items VALUES (3, 'C', 10, 5, 7);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Items
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | size | back      | front         
> -: | :--- | ---: | :-------- | :-------------
>  1 | A    |   10 | red,green | blue          
>  2 | B    |   12 | yellow    | red,yellow    
>  3 | C    |   10 | red,blue  | red,green,blue
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM SimpleItems
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | color         
> -: | :--- | :-------------
>  1 | A    | blue          
>  2 | B    | red,yellow    
>  3 | C    | red,green,blue
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cbbac541c67d0badf851d8f3c8a9adb0)*

As you can see in the example it actually makes that you ask of if, but as it says in the manual numerbs are only a representation of the set.

But i am quite unsure what you want maybe something like

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Items(
>   id int,
>   name tinytext,
>   size int,
>   back SET('red','green','blue','yellow'),
>   front SET('red','green','blue','yellow')  
> );
>
> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SimpleItems AS
> SELECT id, name, COALESCE(front, back) as color, COALESCE(CAST(front AS UNSIGNED), CAST(back AS UNSIGNED)) numb
> FROM Items;
>
> INSERT INTO Items VALUES (1, 'A', 10, 3, 4);
> INSERT INTO Items VALUES (2, 'B', 12, 8, 9);
> INSERT INTO Items VALUES (3, 'C', 10, 5, 7);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *, CAST(front AS UNSiGNED) t FROM Items
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | size | back      | front          |  t
> -: | :--- | ---: | :-------- | :------------- | -:
>  1 | A    |   10 | red,green | blue           |  4
>  2 | B    |   12 | yellow    | red,yellow     |  9
>  3 | C    |   10 | red,blue  | red,green,blue |  7
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM SimpleItems
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | color          | numb
> -: | :--- | :------------- | ---:
>  1 | A    | blue           |    4
>  2 | B    | red,yellow     |    9
>  3 | C    | red,green,blue |    7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2bf2473b73e8d8253d7c2241acb2e4fc)*

Comment: That is true. I'm trying to filter the color column by enabled bits, and that does not work when the column is generated as a varchar. It works in the original table, because the SET is basically just a number (bitmap) as you said. But for some reason the output of COALESCE seems not to be.

Comment: i am not completely sue what yu are expecting number can you get as seen in the second sample